# How can I create timestamped logs and error handle in BASH at the same time?

Tags: bash, logging, error-handling, timestamp

I am writing a BASH script and two of the things I need it to do is:

1. Provide a timestamped log file.
2. Handle errors.

I am finding that these two objectives are clashing.

First of all, I am using the `ts` command to timestamp log entries, e.g. `<a command/subscript> 2>&1 | ts '%H:%M:%S ' >> log`. Note that I need all the lines output of any subscripts to be timestamped too. This works great... until I try to handle errors using exit codes.

Any command that fails (exits with a code of 1) is immediately followed with the `ts` command which executes successfully (exits with a code of 0). This means that I am unable to use the exit codes of the commands to handle errors with the `$?` environment variable because `ts` is always the last command to run and always has an exit code of 0.

Here is the case statement I am using:

```
<command> 2>&1 | ts '%H:%M:%S ' >> log
case $? in
        0)
                echo "Success"
                ;;

        *)
                echo "Failure"
esac
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a foreground pipeline returns, bash saves exit status values of its components to an array variable named [PIPESTATUS](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-PIPESTATUS). In this case, you can use `${PIPESTATUS[0]}` (or just `$PIPESTATUS`; as you're interested in the first component) instead of `$?` to get `<command>`'s exit status value.

Proof of concept:

```
$ false | true | false | true
$ declare -p PIPESTATUS
declare -a PIPESTATUS=([0]="1" [1]="0" [2]="1" [3]="0")
```

Comment: This worked a charm. Thanks a lot! I didn't know about PIPESTATUS.